# Django model constrains

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I am trying to create an Asset management system and the model AssetLog is responsible of making sure that a user is assigned to a single computer and a computer is assigned to a single user.
And i have managed to set that up but now, Trying to update an object from current to previous is now not allowing me to do so even using the Django Admin panel

```
class AssetLog(models.Model):
    Used            = "U"
    Previous        = "P"
    Current         = "C"
    status_choices = [
        (Used, "Used"),
        (Previous, "Previous"),
        (Current, "Current"),
    ]
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices= status_choices,
        default=Current,
    )
    user_id         = models.ForeignKey(Account,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    asset_num       = models.ForeignKey(Computer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    allocated_on    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    Location        = models.ForeignKey(Location,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def clean(self):
        # Checking if the user and the computer have been logged
        a =  AssetLog.objects.filter(Q(asset_num=self.asset_num) & Q(user_id=self.user_id)).exists()
        b = AssetLog.objects.filter(Q(asset_num=self.asset_num)).exists()
        c =  AssetLog.objects.filter(Q(user_id=self.user_id)).exists()
        try:
            if a:
                
                computer =  AssetLog.objects.get(asset_num=self.asset_num)
                if computer.status == 'C':
                    msg = 'The Asset is being used by- ' + computer.user_id.first_name
                    raise ValidationError(msg)
                                    
            elif b:
                computer =  AssetLog.objects.get(asset_num=self.asset_num)
                if computer.status == 'C':
                    msg = 'The Asset is being used by- ' + computer.user_id.first_name
                    raise ValidationError(msg)
                            
            elif c:
                computer =  AssetLog.objects.get(user_id=self.user_id)
                if computer.status == 'C':
                    msg = 'The User has a machine allocated to him or her already' 
                    raise ValidationError(msg)
                
        except AssetLog.DoesNotExist:
            pass`
```